# Adding spring mvc to a spring java "desktop" application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Java desktop application which uses spring framework and I need to replace the Swing UI with a web front end. I understand that I will need to adapt many things to make things work with the MVC architecture.
My concrete question is the following:

**Will my application now have to run entirely in the application server?**

I would appreciate if anyone could point me to some documentation that goes through a similar process.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless the application communicates (with sockets, RMI, web services or whatever) with another application, then yes, Spring MVC is servlet-based, and needs a servlet container to run.

Comment: My application does communicate with android clients using MQTT, would that represent a problem?

Comment: When you say _web front end_, do you mean that the application no longer runs on the desktop?

Comment: What I mean when I say "web front end" is to make the GUI accessible using a web browser so we can interact remotely with the application without the need of Remote Desktop, for example. I am not sure if that implies that the entire application will no longer run as a desktop application or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Technically* yes, but [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) makes it trivial to set up an embedded servlet container and package your entire application as a runnable jar. This is how we're deploying our applications to production; the only thing we need is a JRE on the server VM, and `java -jar` takes care of all of it.

I recommend using Maven with the Spring Boot plugin (there's also a Gradle plugin) with [the `repackage` goal](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html), and using the lightweight Undertow servlet engine instead of the default Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good approach. I only had problems with multiple slf4j bindings since I was already using it but works now quite well.